# Linking multiple phones to a single twilio account

Tags: twilio

How does one link a single twilio number to multiple phones such that:

1. When new people text the twilio number, all of the phones linked to the twilio number receive the text.
2. When any one of the twilio phones respond to the text, it appears to the original texter that a single number is responding to them (irregardless of which of the twilio phones sends the text).
3. Picture texts work also in the way described in (1)-(2).

This is very similar to what Google Voice can do, except google voice sometimes doesn't work with picture texts.

Answer (score 0):

You would need a backend of some sort, where you can store subscribers for a number, you can then handle in your language of choice, when you receive a sms perhaps containing the word "subscribe", you would then simply save that into your backend along with the number that the sms was received upon.

When receiving a sms that contains other text, you would then simply query your backend and find all the numbers that have subscribed to the number that you have just received the sms on, you would then simply use the Twilio api, to send the message to all the results from your backend query.

You could also allow unsubscribe functionality, where users only have to send unsubscribe to the number, and you would remove them from your backend or flag them as to not send to them again.